# How can I create a middleware in an endpoint that does a validation on the parameters that are sent from the client side?

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, excuse my ignorance. I am using C#, ASP.NET Core 3.1 with Entity Framework.

I have an endpoint like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Usuario>> Post([FromBody] City  city) 
    {
            context.City.Add(city);
            try
            {
                 await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var error = _utils.generateError(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                return Ok(error);
            }
             return Ok(new { ok = true, message = "City created" });
    }
```

The user sends an object like this:

```
{"city": "Manizales"}
```

I want to make a verification that if `city = Manizales` allows to continue with my endpoint.

I am very confused but I don't know if something like this exists but it works as a middleware:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [MyCustomMiddleWare]
   .
   .

 public class MyCustomMiddleWare
 {
    .
    .
    if (data.city == "Manizales")
    {
        continue
    }
 }
```

How can I do it?

**NOTE:**

I'll tell you about my real example, I have an application where users have roles and depending on their role they can do an action or not. For example, if the role is administrator, the user can access the endpoints where there is data deletion, if the role is not administrator, he should not even be able to enter.

that's why I want to fix it with a middleware. To do this, I decode the token that the user sends in the web request, and if the corresponding role is in the decoding of the token, it can continue with the endpoint.

Comment: Do you want to validate on all your requests? If yes, then middleware are the way to go. If not, it is better to create a filter and add it on the endpoint.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri thanks, I want to do a validation to most of my endpoints ..

Comment: If it is most of your endpoints, filter based approach is going to do well. Middleware gets hooked to your http pipeline and all requests get passed to it. To do it only for specific endpoints, you'll have to inject some sort of logic into your middleware and that is not a concern that middleware needs to be aware of.

Comment: I'll tell you about my real example, I have an application where users have roles and depending on their role they can do an action or not. For example, if the role is administrator, the user can access the endpoints where there is data deletion, if the role is not administrator, he should not even be able to enter.
that's why I want to fix it with a middleware.
To do this, I decode the token that the user sends in the web request, and if the corresponding role is in the decoding of the token, it can continue with the endpoint.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri I don't think it's convenient to do it with a filter, but with a middleware.

Comment: you may use a validation attributes into the received object instead of middelware then you can check if this.ModelState.IsValid and if not you can return Bad request where users see the error message specifyed in the validation attribute. if the request should be filtered by role use authorozeattrobute there u can specify the roles allowed

Comment: @spzvtbg how can I do it in a endpoint?  Can you please read the comment I wrote before yours? is it still the best way?

Comment: See here:   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @yavg - What you are trying to do is Authorization like other users pointed out. Depending on how you are doing it (be it roles or claims), you need to build an authorization filter and add it on the endpoints you want to be authorized before being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by using **IAuthorizationFilter**.

Here you can customize the logic using OnAuthorization method.

The **IAuthorizationFilter's** **OnAuthorization()** method will be called before your controller is initialized and based on code, if the user is admin, you can allow to go with the endpoint, that is the controller will be initialized and controller object will created and then the action method will be called. if not then request can redirected or can show error message, that is depending on your business need.

You can find the similar example over here.
https://blog.honosoft.com/2019/07/09/dotnet-core-what-can-you-do-in-case-you-wish-to-authorize-without-authorize/

Comment: @yavg does this help ?